# Scoping parent / grandparent

Tags: c#, scope

Suppose I have a set of classes:

```
class runState
{
    mStart()
    {
    }

    mStarted()
    {
    }
}

class myClassParent
{
    runState myRunState;    
}

class myGrandParent
{
    myClassParent MyClassParent;
}
```

Is there any way to scope runState.mStarted to be visible to MyClassParent but not visible to the grandparent while making runState.mStart visible to MyClassParent and myClassGrandparent?

In other words the grandparent should be able to call the parent's runState.mStart but not be able to call the runState.mStarted.  Only the parent should be able to call runState.MStarted.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `mStarted` `internal` and ensure that `myClassParent` is in the same assembly as `runState` and have `myGrandParent` in another assembly.

Since by default methods are `private`, you will need to make `mStart` public.

Comment: classes by default are internal, and your work says create new assembly everytime in such situation.